# Getting an error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I run the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "allen123";
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $username, $password);
?>
```

I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No >such file or directory' in /Users/idrisk/Colourity/site/index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 >/Users/idrisk/Colourity/site/index.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', >'allen123') #1 {main} thrown in /Users/idrisk/Colourity/site/index.php on line 4

Any ideas? I downloaded the PDO drivers via Macports by the way

**EDIT**

```
To use mysqlnd with a local MySQL server, edit /opt/local/etc/php55/php.ini and set     mysql.default_socket, mysqli.default_socket and pdo_mysql.default_socket to the path
to your MySQL server's socket file.

For mysql5, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
For mysql51, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql51/mysqld.sock
For mysql55, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql55/mysqld.sock
For mysql56, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql56/mysqld.sock
For mariadb, use /opt/local/var/run/mariadb/mysqld.sock
For percona, use /opt/local/var/run/percona/mysqld.sock

--->  Cleaning php55-mysql
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but I think that the physical path to your `pdo_mysql.default_socket` defined in `my.cnf` differs from the physical location of `mysqld.sock` on the server.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: +1 (but you probably meant `php.ini` for `pdo_mysql.default_socket` does not match `my.cnf` for `socket`; `pdo_mysql.default_socket` is not in `my.cnf`).

Comment: @Amadan D'oh..I'm wrong, long day, yes, php.ini :)

Comment: If you are on ubuntu or something similar. execute this in your terminal `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Comment: I had to since I installed the drivers via Macports and check the post edit, thats what I was told. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Krimson: He's not on ubuntu or something similar, he said he was using Macports, thus OSX.

Comment: Can you verify that the physical path is proper then? Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Can you just check what your `/etc/my.cnf` says for `socket`? Actually, do you even have `my.cnf`? If not, `sudo port install mysql5-server`. (Hmm, now that I think about it, maybe Macports move `my.cnf` to `/opt/local` as well, check there too - I'm using Homebrew, not too experienced with Macports)

Comment: Don't have one. I'm installing `mysql5-server` now. @Amadan

Comment: Also assuming you're on Mac any ideas why I can't edit the `php.ini` via a text editor, rather `sudo nano` even through permission are on read and write? @Amadan

Comment: @user302975 You probably have read/write permissions only for the owner of the file. You need to set write permissions to "other" to be able to write it. However that is very bad. Use sudo. System files should not be world-writable.

Comment: P.S. You did remember to restart your web server after you make these edits to the system files, right?

Comment: What is the value of `pdo_mysql.default_socket` in php.ini? If it's not empty, try setting it to an empty string. That way it will use the default socket.

Comment: Also, you can open it with any text editor. For example, you can do `sudo open -a TextEdit php.ini` to edit it as admin in TextEdit (comparable for other editors). You're not limited to `nano`.

Comment: @Mike: impractical, since Macports install to a non-standard location.

Comment: Does mysqli or ext/mysql produce any sort of error, or is it just PDO?

Comment: So what am I looking for in the `my.cnf`? @Amadan

Comment: Its `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` Just like Macports said @Mi

Comment: At the moment mysqli works fine. @Mike

Comment: Is `pdo_mysql.default_socket` the same as `mysqli.default_socket` in your php.ini file?

Comment: No `mysqli.default_socket` is empty. @Mike

Comment: @user302975 Since mysqli is working, try doing the same for pdo, even though Amadan says it's impractical, it's worth a shot.

Comment: It appears to work dude. Thanks soo much. Get an answer written up and I'll accept it ;) @Mike

Comment: Glad you have your machine working, even if I was wrong. As I said, not that much experience with Macports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an invalid socket in your php.ini file. Change the `pdo_mysql.default_socket` setting to an empty string to use the default socket.